# How can i change the value of a resource?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have two resource as this:

```
<Color x:Key="Color1">#17110F</Color>
<Color x:Key="Color2">#FDFDFD</Color>
```

if i use aso, this work for me

```
App.Current.Resources["Color1"] = Color.FromHex("#FDFDFD");
```

but i want use so: that is possible?

```
Style color = App.Current.Resources["Color1"];
```

this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want but the value you are getting from the Resources is a `Color` not a `Style`. You will also need to cast the value since the returned value comes in the form of an Object.

```
var color2 = (Color)App.Current.Resources["Color2"];
```

or

```
Color color2 = (Color)App.Current.Resources["Color2"];
```

The above line should give you what you want.

Hope this helps.-